# Why my slider is stacking on top of each other? New To sliders

Tags: html, css, image, slider

I am new to sliders so sorry if my code looks funky. Can you please give me an idea why my slider is stacking on top of each other instead of going left sliding like normal?

```css
@keyframes slide {
     0% { left: 0%; }
    20% { left: 0%; }
    35% { left: -100%; }
    45% { left: -100%; }
    50% { left: -200%; }
    70% { left: -200%; }
    75% { left: -300%; }
    95% { left: -300%; }
    100% { left: 0%; }
}

.slider{
    width: 100%;
    height: 480px;
}

.slider .slideimg{
    width: 100%;
    height: 480px;
    position: absolute;
    animation: 30s slide infinite;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slideimg:nth-child(1){
    background-image: url(../images/homeimages/Terminator-Dark-Fate-Banner.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.slideimg:nth-child(2){
    background-image: url(../images/homeimages/alladin.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.slideimg:nth-child(3){
    background-image: url(../images/homeimages/frozen-ii-2020.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: top;
}


.slider .slideimg:hover, 
.sliderbtn a:hover, .sliderbtn a:visited:hover {
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

```html
<!--- Slider---->
    
    
               <div class="slider">
                   <div class="slideimg">
                        <div class="slidetitle">
                           <h1>Terminator: Dark Fate</h1>
                           <p>Subheader Infor</p>
                           <p class="sliderbtn"><a href="#">Get Ticket</a></p>
                           <p class="sliderbtn"><a href="#">View Trailer</a></p>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                  
                   <div class="slideimg">
                       <div class="slidetitle">
                           <h1>Aladin</h1>
                           <p>Subheader Infor</p>
                           <p class="sliderbtn"><a href="#">Get Ticket</a></p>
                           <p class="sliderbtn"><a href="#">View Trailer</a></p>
                       </div>
                    </div>
    
                   <div class="slideimg">
                       <div class="slidetitle">
                           <h1>Frozen: 2</h1>
                           <p>Subheader Infor</p>
                           <p class="sliderbtn"><a href="#">Get Ticket</a></p>
                           <p class="sliderbtn"><a href="#">View Trailer</a></p>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                   
                    <div class="slideimg">
                        <div class="slidetitle">
                           <h1>Terminator: Dark Fate</h1>
                           <p>Subheader Infor</p>
                           <p class="sliderbtn"><a href="#">Get Ticket</a></p>
                           <p class="sliderbtn"><a href="#">View Trailer</a></p>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
```

Comment: Hello @Scarlett. You can use slick slider. Its easy to use. I am attaching the link. If you need any help. i am here to help you. Let me know.  http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: thanks Ravti i can check it out, but still would like a resolution for what i have now. Because i need the background image which a lot of people don't use.

Comment: I am checking your code also. If any changes i will let you know.

Comment: @RevtiShah okie thanks buddy i still looking for resolution for mine, i know a lot people don't use background image much but i need it that way.

Comment: Can you tell me what excatly output you want? So i will make it for you.

Comment: I got it . you want background-image for slider. right?

Comment: yes correct and a caption to be able to edit it :)

Comment: Caption like "Terminator: Dark Fate" should be editable at a time right?

Comment: @RevtiShah ya as long as caption is editable to like change colors, sizing, margin and etc. :) and would like it separated from the button i need to make.

Comment: Okay give me some time. I will make it for you.

Comment: @RevtiShah oh i think i misunderstood, i need each one editable for each slider yes.

Comment: @RevtiShah thank you i appreciate it!! I still in college for coding so learning stuff still :)

Comment: okay i will help you out.

Comment: Hello @scarelet. I have a query. Do you need caption editable by css or you want edit on slide?

Comment: Hey @RevtiShah i need to be able to edit it in html and css, would prefer to edit in CSS if possible because i would like to edit specific areas. Hope that answer the question :)

Comment: yes. i am done with slider. i will share you in few minutes.

Comment: @RevtiShah yay thank you so much! :) do you have social media i can follow your work on? :)

Comment: yeah i am on social media. You can find it by my name. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am attaching code. Please review it. If any changes then let me know.

here is the link:

https://jsfiddle.net/k4gu0t7v/16/

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}

body {
  background-color: #000000;
}

.crossfade>figure {
  animation: imageAnimation 24s linear infinite 0s;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  color: transparent;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
}

.crossfade>figure:nth-child(1) {
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/id/1000/1000/500');
}

.crossfade>figure:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 6s;
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/id/1001/1000/500');
}

.crossfade>figure:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 12s;
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/id/1075/1000/500');
}

.crossfade>figure:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 18s;
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/id/1076/1000/500');
}

@keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    opacity: 0;
  }

  8% {
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    opacity: 1;
  }

  17% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  
  25% {
    opacity: 0
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }

}

.slidetitle {
  padding: 20px;
}

.slidetitle h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #000
}

.slidetitle p {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #444
}
.slide-button{
  margin-top:20px;
  display:flex;
}
.sliderbtn{
  margin-right:15px;
}
.sliderbtn{
  border:2px solid #444;
  padding:6px 12px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.sliderbtn a{
  text-decoration:none;
}
.white{
  color:#fff !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="crossfade">
  <!--1-->
  <figure>
    <div class="slidetitle">
      <h1>Terminator: Dark Fate</h1>
      <p>Subheader Infor</p>
      <div class="slide-button">
        <p class="sliderbtn"><a href="#">Get Ticket</a></p>
        <p class="sliderbtn"><a href="#">View Trailer</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </figure>
  <!--2-->
  <figure>
    <div class="slidetitle">
      <h1>Aladin</h1>
      <p>Subheader Infor</p>
      <div class="slide-button">
        <p class="sliderbtn"><a href="#">Get Ticket</a></p>
        <p class="sliderbtn"><a href="#">View Trailer</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </figure>
  <!--3-->
  <figure>
    <div class="slidetitle">
      <h1 class="white">Frozen: 2</h1>
      <p class="white">Subheader Infor</p>
      <div class="slide-button">
        <p class="sliderbtn"><a href="#">Get Ticket</a></p>
        <p class="sliderbtn"><a href="#">View Trailer</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </figure>
  <!--4-->
  <figure>
    <div class="slidetitle">
      <h1>Terminator: Dark Fate</h1>
      <p>Subheader Infor</p>
      <div class="slide-button">
        <p class="sliderbtn"><a href="#">Get Ticket</a></p>
        <p class="sliderbtn"><a href="#">View Trailer</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: this looks awesome! anyway though to just make it slide and not fade? :)

Comment: I do fade effect.If you want to slide then Let me check. i will tell you whether it should be sliding or not.

Comment: yes thank you! Also anyway to avoid the position absolute? because it tops my navigation.

Comment: please avoid the position absolute.

Comment: Do you wanna use bootstrap 4 for slider?

Comment: hmm i try to avoid it but i can look into it.

Comment: I heading to sleep for now, but whatever you think is best for my slider to work please let me know. :)

Comment: Okay. i am sharing you another link of bootstrap 4. you can use it if you want. or you can use my code also. https://startbootstrap.com/snippets/full-slider/